# Need to debug a dll file written in VS2010 to catch an exception

Tags: c++, boost, dll

I currently have a C++ dll file (built in Vs2010) in which exported methods have been defined in the .def file.I am using a method of this dll in a C# application using the following syntax

```
    [DllImport("C:\\Filename.dll")]
    public static extern int SomeMethod(int par_a , int par_b);
```

After making some changes to the method I am getting a debug assertion error from the dll file through the C# application. The error window that pops up just pops up for a second or so thus I am unable to get the details of the error. Is there any way for me to find out how and why this exception occured. My dll file usually logs error in this case it did nothing. Is there a way for me to insert breakpoints in my dll file ?

Comment: Focus on the functions you're calling and look for assertions of invalid state.

Comment: @ACB could you explain what you mean by invalid state ?

Comment: Assertion error is the result of a specific situtation that the programmer who wrote it knew about. He put code in place to check for this situation and said "If this value is x, then this is an invalid state, and the code should throw an error.".. This is a default state. check the cpp code for any assert statement.

Comment: My code uses other libraries. I myself have not placed any assertions however other libraries might have. I am currently going over this issue

Comment: did you checked the dll file